# Calendar sync nextcloud past events

Tags: 22.04, sync, calendar

I have an issue with Calendar 41.2 bundled in Ubuntu 22.04. Everything is working fine, except if I keep my laptop powered down for some day, but I still continue using NextCloud calendar from my phone.

When I bootstrap the laptop again, it doesn't sync calendar events inserted by phone if they are already past. Also manual sync does not solve.

Is it possible to keep Calendar synced also with past events?